# Why do in general stars twinkle and planets don't?

Tags: amateur-observing, atmospheric-effects

I got an email update on what can be observed this week.

> Jupiter looks like a bright yellow-white star, almost as bright as
> Mars. Saturn is about 10 moon widths to the left and slightly above,
> and is much fainter, but still bright enough to see from Cambridge. In
> general, planets can be distinguished by their lack of twinkling,
> while stars do twinkle.

Why is that the case that stars twinkle, and planets don't? I am aware of variable stars, but I don't think the email means that, since twinkle usually means much more rapid change than variable stars usually exhibit.